# How to prioritize Bean Definition based on its presence with annotation?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working on data layer that I want to activate one implementation to another based on maven dependency. For example, I have UserDAO as interface, and the first implementation is SQL-based implementation as `SQLUserDAO`, which is my default choice. Alternatively, I want to have a second implementation with LDAP support, `LDAPUserDAO`. What I am looking for is if both of them present in dependency list, `LDAPUserDAO` should be in use, otherwise `SQLUserDAO` as base implementation when `LDAPUserDAO` is not there. Summary, I want to give higher priority to `LDAPUserDAO` over `SQLUserDAO` if both checked out.

**Interface**

```
public interface UserDAO {
```

**SQL Implementation**

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class SQLUserDAO implements UserDAO {
```

**LDAP Implementation**

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class LDAPUserDAO implements UserDAO {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html):

> "Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple
>   candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If
>   exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the
>   autowired value. This annotation is semantically equivalent to the
>    element's primary attribute in Spring XML."

For more special cases also an implementation of a BeanFactoryPostProcessor with PriorityOrdered can be helpful. http://rachitskillisaurus.blogspot.co.at/2013/10/spring-force-bean-to-be-first-to.html

Comment: Correct answer. Just one addition: you dont't need to implement a post processor. The annotations `@Order` and `@Priority` on class level are taken into account by spring 4+ directly.